# how to get always the billing address same as the shipping address M2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I want o have always the same billing address asthe shipping address chosen but when i add new address and choose the second i get  a different address and the chechbox is unchecked so how to force this to be always checked any idea please and thanks in advance